# How to increase search radius for a road link for a waypoint (Fleet Telematics API)

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to calculate route summary for a truck using Fleet Telematics Custom Routes API (https://cle.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json).
And I'm getting an error saying: Cannot match *lat/long* onto a road link with 100.0m search radius.

The error is, in fact, correct since Truck is in the middle of a big warehouse and there are no roads in 100 radius.

So the question is how can I increase search radius to prevent this error. OR there are any other options?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a radius parameter in meters after the position, ex for 500m:

```
waypoint0=geo!48.85718,2.34141;500
```

Source doc:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html

Comment: unfortunatelly not. I'm using using Fleet Telematics API and extra parameter for waypoint are not supported except stopOver!. Source: http://cre.api.here.com/swagger-ui.html?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
As it says:
&waypoint1=stopOver,300! 50.12,8.65. None of the optional specifications geo!, stopOver!, passThrough!, altitude, transitRadius, custom label, heading, !StreetPosition, !LinkPosition are currently supported.

Comment: Oh. Maybe you could then ask the HERE support if an API change is in the works ?